# Unable to append value to colums. Getting error IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, iteration

I am trying to get the ODI data from the link http://www.espncricinfo.com/australia/content/player/325026.html.
I want to add the heading and below that add the columns.
My code is :

```
def parse(self, response):

    #extracting the entire class
    batting=response.xpath('//*[@class="engineTable"]').extract()[0]

    #extracting batting scores
    #using selector
    y=str("#")+batting+str("#")
    sel=Selector(text=y)

    #extracting column headings
    header=sel.xpath('//thead/tr/th/text()').extract()

    #values
    data= sel.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[contains(@title, "record rank: 2")]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract()

    col=[]
    i=0
    for head in header:
        i+=1
        #creating an empty list with the
        #values appended
        col.append((head,[]))
    i=0
    for j in range(len(data)):
        #T is the j th row
        T=data[j]

        for dat in T:
            i+=1
            #appending to empty list
            col[i][1].append(dat)

    #creating dict
    Dict={title:column for (title,column) in col}
    df=pd.DataFrame(Dict)
    print (df)
```

I am getting error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ```

```
File "E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)File "C:\Users\DUDE\Desktop\odi_data\odi_data\spiders\odi.py", line 41, in parse. col[i][1].append(dat)
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Cant figure out what is wrong in the code. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Use this selector `'td:contains("ODIs") ~ td::text'` for `ODIs` and `'.engineTable:contains("ODIs") > thead th::text'` for headers to make them less verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is logic error in your code. The follows worked:

```
import pandas as pd

from parsel import Selector


def parse(response):

    # extracting the entire class
    batting = response.xpath('//*[@class="engineTable"]').extract()[0]

    # extracting batting scores
    # using selector
    y = str("#") + batting + str("#")
    sel = Selector(text=y)

    # extracting column headings
    header = sel.xpath('//thead/tr/th/text()').extract()

    # values
    data = sel.xpath(
        '//tbody/tr/td[contains(@title, "record rank: 2")]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract()

    col = []
    # i = 0
    for head in header:
        # i += 1
        # creating an empty list with the
        # values appended
        col.append((head, []))

    i = 0
    for j in range(len(data)):
        # T is the j th row
        T = data[j]
        # appending to empty list
        col[i][1].append(T)

        i += 1

    # creating dict
    Dict = {title: column for (title, column) in col}

    print(Dict)
    df = pd.DataFrame(Dict)
    print(df)


import requests

url = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/australia/content/player/325026.html'
r = requests.get(url)
# print(r.text)
parse(Selector(r.text))
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should put `i += 1` behind `col[i][1].append(dat)`